# Intercept and categorical variables

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

Suppose we have a linear model where ${variety_i}$ is an indicator for types of plant (A,B,C,D).

$y_i = \mu + \beta{variety_i} + \beta_1 rain_i +  \epsilon_i$

So we would have $\beta_A , \beta_B, \beta_C, \beta_D$. Now here the reference would be A so then would we say $\beta_A = 0$?

Also, if I plot this model in R, is the (intercept term) just equal to $\mu + \beta_A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the restriction you set.
You can set any of them as 0 or set the sum as zero.

Comment: Thank you for the response! How are we able to just set them as 0? Also, if I plot this model in R, is the (intercept term) just equal to $\mu + \beta_A$?

Comment: If you code in R, it uses corner stone restriction, i.e. set beta_a as 0

Comment: I see. Thank you